# NSFetchedResultController. Calculating sectionNameKeyPath with expression/by condition

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Suppose a table named testTable:

```
(NSNumber*) numValue
(NSString*) stringValue
```

Then suppose about 50 records in it. `numValue` different in every record.
If I create NSFetchedResultController like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                            initWithFetchRequest: request 
                            managedObjectContext: context 
                            sectionNameKeyPath: @"numValue" 
                            cacheName: @"testTable"]];
```

I'll get 50 sections then.

My question is:
How can I get 2 sections:
First containing records with `numValue` less than some `x` and second with records where `numValue` bigger than the same `x`.

For `x = 15` it could look like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                            initWithFetchRequest: request 
                            managedObjectContext: context 
                            sectionNameKeyPath: @"numValue > 15" 
                            cacheName: @"testTable"]];
```

**Possible solutions are:**

1. We can edit our Entity as @Dima said.
2. In the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` we can just look at the section names and compare them to `x`. Then we could look at these names in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and calculate what we need to. But that's feels dirty too. Better than first approach, but still.

**UPDATE:**
Well, I've almost figured out 3rd way to do that. Thanks to the @Dima's link.
Here is the code:

```
[self setFetchedResultsController: [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
    initWithFetchRequest: request 
    managedObjectContext: context 
    sectionNameKeyPath: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"numValue.compare(%f)", x]];
```

But there is a problem with KVC compliance: 
methods(selectors) with arguments aren't KVC compliant obviously. 
Any idea for workaround?

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112521/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-sections-created-by-first-letter-of-a-string) answer as a reference.

Add an optional attribute to the entity and make it a transient property.

Then create a getter (assuming your property is called `sectionGroup`)

```
- (NSNumber *) sectionGroup
{
  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionGroup"];
  NSNumber *group = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
  if(numValue > 15)
  {
    group = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
  }
  [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionGroup"];
  return group;
}
```

Now, you can use `sectionGroup` as your sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: I had to say in OP that I want another way, because change the entity for such things feels like kind of dirty.