# How can i filter NSMutableArray by firstName with non-alphabetical characters

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios5

I want to filter the Array, where name starts with non-alphabetical characters. I want to display the contacts where firstName starts with non-alphabetical characters under different section in table view. I tried below code, but it crashing , please find reason below:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(firstName BEGINSWITH[c] %@)",arrIndex]; //where arrIndex is the array of alphabetical characeters.
  NSArray  *arrContacts = [arrayTotalContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = iPhone rhs = (
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H,
    I,
    J,
    K,
    L,
    M,
    N,
    O,
    P,
    Q,
    R,
    S,
    T,
    U,
    V,
    W,
    X,
    Y,
    Z
))'

arrayTotalContacts has the below data:

```
(
{
    firstName = iPhone;
    lastName = "";
},
{
    firstName = Madhu;
    lastName = "";
},
{
    firstName = "Swa";
    lastName = "";
},
{
    firstName = TechV;
    lastName = "";
},
{
    firstName = Vedika;
    lastName = Vt;
}
)
```

Comment: Edit you question with datasource.

Comment: @Reformer: I edited the question with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression with a Core Data predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (firstName MATCHES %@)", @"^[A-Za-z].*"]
```

where `^[A-Za-z].*` is a regex for all strings that do start with A-Z or a-z.
To make it work with letters from foreign languages as well (e.g. "Ä"), use
the Unicode property name:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(firstName MATCHES %@)", @"^\\p{Letter}.*"]
```

Here `^\\p{Letter}.*` is a regex for all strings that start with a letter.

But if this is for a table view, you might better use a fetched results controller
and its `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter. See for example here:

- [NSFetchedResultsController with sections created by first letter of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112521/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-sections-created-by-first-letter-of-a-string)

for some examples how to group a table view according to the initial letter. It should be
possible to modify the code to group all names that do not start with a letter into
a separate group.

Comment: This works fine for me, but if the name is empty i am not getting that object in the result, i want that object in the result, how can i fix it?

Comment: @PalchuriSudheerKumar: I have updated the answer, it should now work with an empty string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
NSArray * arrContacts = [arrayTotalContacts  valueForKeyPath:@"firstName"];
```

Hope it helps :)