# How can I have more than one item under a section in my tableview sorted alphabetically?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have implemented the FetchedControllerDelegate, and I have the table view sorted so that everything is displayed alphabetically, and the section headers are working. However, for a section with letter "T", for example, the tableview has two different sections if the name of the place isn't the *exact* same word. For example, for "Taco Bell" and "Texas", they are each under a different section with the label "T". I want it so that every word that starts with a "T" is under the "T" section name. I've found information on how to do this but it has been for Obj-C instead of Swift. Also, there's been answers involving setting a transient property but I don't know where to start to implement that

[How to use the first character as a section name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741093/how-to-use-the-first-character-as-a-section-name)

[NSFetchedResultsController with sections created by first letter of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112521/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-sections-created-by-first-letter-of-a-string)

```
    // Add Sort Descriptors
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, 
        managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, 
        sectionNameKeyPath: "name", cacheName: nil)
```

Then the table view methods:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sectionForSectionIndexTitle(title, atIndex: index)
}

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        if let char = currentSection.name.characters.first {
            return String(char)
        }
        return currentSection.name
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a computed property in your `NSManagedObject` subclass and return name's first character there like,

```
var nameFirstChar: String {
    get {
        if let char = self.name?.characters.first {
            return String(char)
        }
        return "#"
    }
}
```

Now set nameFirstChar as your section keypath like,

```
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "nameFirstChar", cacheName: nil)
```